JPA subquery not returning the same result as DB query
With a subquery and a parameter (oracle 19), I dont get the same result as if I am hitting directly the DB with the supposed generated SQL, is there some optimization am not aware and should do it a different way?
Kotlin but I bet you get the point in Java as well using hibernate...
I dont get why...
val lId = 103
getExadataEntityManager().createNativeQuery(
    """SELECT 
        id 
        FROM Person 
        WHERE name=(
            SELECT name FROM Person 
                                    WHERE id=:anId
                                    )""".trimMargin()
)
.setParameter("anId", lId)
.resultList
        

returns me 1 item, where when I hit the same qry
SELECT id FROM Person WHERE name=(SELECT name FROM Person WHERE id=103)
I get 2 results
What am I doing wrong?
Note that nor is that working with a join like
SELECT 
    p1.id 
FROM Person p1
INNER JOIN Person p2 ON p1.name=p2.name
WHERE p1.id=:anId


val lId = "Bob" that doesn't look right to me. In the direct SQL, you query for ID=103 and in code you say Bob?

Here are some common reasons why a query returns different results from different clients. They are listed roughly in the order of likelihood, where the first reason happens to database developers maybe once a week, and the last reason happens maybe once a decade.

Uncommitted changes in a session.
The SQL being run is not what you think it is. Find the actual submitted queries in GV$SQL to check.
Connected to the wrong user. Run select user from dual to check.
Connected to the wrong database or container. Run select sys_context('USERENV','DB_NAME') from dual to check
Sessions are reading from different default schemas. Run select sys_context('USERENV', 'current_schema') from dual to check.
Sessions are using different NLS comparisons, such as LINGUISTIC in one session and BINARY in another.  Run select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_COMP' to check.
Virtual private database is hiding data from specific connections.
DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE or some other evil plan management feature is silently rewriting queries. Check the "Note" section of explain plans for both queries.
Wrong-results and a performance bug working together. For example, if there is a corrupt index, but the index is only used in one session perhaps because of session settings.

